# Trying to Build a Servomotor Tester

Tags: servo

I tried to build a very simple servomotor tester.

I am using astable mode with a potentiometer and resistor on a NE555 to generate a 20 ms period. It has a correct frequency on the output between 50.5 Hz and 49.97 Hz and around 0.7 V so I think this part is OK.

[image]
oh C3 has bad value on schematic but it is a 0.1mF in real.

To drive a servomotor I tried the following circuit but nothing moved:

[image]

What I've tried:

- Changing transistors (2N2222/BC547/2N3904)
- Changing resistors (but no values)
- Changing resistors values to 1K
- Changed 555 (tried 3 different ones)
- Changed servomotors (6 ones)

I had here a toy-like oscilloscope capture at servosignal point

[image: scope image]

[original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HXxb.jpg)

but its voltage measurement is bad (compared to the multimeter(s))

Comment: Please add your 555 circuit to that diagram, and a picture of or link to a catalog page of the "servomotor".  If it's an RC type servo then it wants positive-going pulses at a frame rate of 50-60Hz and pulse widths of 1-2ms.  If it's an *industrial* servomotor then it's a completely different animal, with a completely different set of care and feeding instructions.

Comment: Yes it is RC type, I'm going to add a schematic of the 555 part but I 'm nearly sure it is ok, I already used the similar for schematic for another use.  I'm going to add a schematic

Comment: Do you have an oscilloscope?  This would be much easier to debug with scope traces.

Comment: Doesn't a model aircraft servo need a pulse between 1 and 2 ms wide?

Comment: A multimeter isn't going to display a reliable voltage when you're working with pulses like this, the oscilloscope is more accurate. Do you have a link to the servomotor datasheet? What voltage is it expecting?

Comment: I tried many different servomotors as said http://www.ee.ic.ac.uk/pcheung/teaching/DE1_EE/stores/sg90_datasheet.pdf this one for example

Comment: @francoisP, from that datasheet it looks like "servosignal" also needs to be 5 V, additionally, the positioning is dependent on the pulse width. So it may move once, and then not again if you're sending a constant pulse width. In your schematic, when you power the transistor, servosignal gets pulled to 0 V.